# Pointer offset is incorrect when using multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, arm, multiple-inheritance

I am encountering a bug in some code which uses multiple inheritance when accessing a member variable.  Unfortunately, I **cannot** provide a minimum reproducible example that you can run, but I can provide a bunch of information as to what I am seeing.  My code is compiled using GCC for ARM.

To give the rough idea, this is what I have (not my actual code):

```
class Foo;

class MyClass:
    public A,
    public B,
    public C
{
public:
    Foo& foo() { 
        assert(_ptr);
        return *_ptr;
    }

private:
   //A bunch of other members
   std::unqiue_ptr<Foo> _ptr; //Located 0x2710 from start of this
};
```

Where classes A, B, and C also multiply inherit from other classes.  For example:

```
class A :
    public Q,
    public R,
    public S
{
//Data members and functions...
};
```

I have a pointer to MyClass as follows:

```
MyClass* myClassPtr; //Points to 0x20005c98
```

Where the address of myClassPtr->_ptr should be 0x200083A8 (0x20005c98 + 0x2710)

However, when I step through my assembly, this is what I see

```
0800883a:   ldr     r6, [r6, #4]
0800883c:   add.w   r3, r4, #94208  ; 0x17000
08008840:   str.w   r6, [r3, #3308] ; 0xcec

08008844:   add.w   r3, r6, #8192   ; 0x2000
08008848:   ldr.w   r3, [r3, #1532] ; 0x5fc
```

The str.w is the place at which my myClassPtr is getting set, thus r6 should hold the address to the start of my MyClass instance.  Which I can verify to be true (r6 holds 0x20005c98).

The instruction at 08008844 (add.w) should then be moving to the appropriate offset within the unique_ptr in order to check if it is null.  However, 0x20005c98 + 0x2000 is 0x20007C98 which is well **BEFORE** the start of the _ptr variable...

I've tried with multiple versions of the compiler as well just to make sure this wasn't a bug.

Thus, I know its my fault and that the problem is related to the multiple inheritance, but I just can't figure out what the problem actually is.  Some general insight into what to look for/test would be very helpful.

By the way, I call the same function (the bool cast operator of the pointer) within the constructor of MyClass.  It generated the following assembly:

```
0802f5a2:   add.w   r3, r4, #8192   ; 0x2000
0802f5a6:   ldr.w   r5, [r3, #1812] ; 0x714
```

In this case, r4 is holding the this pointer, but otherwise it is identical to the other call to the function except that this time, the offset is correct...

Comment: Is `virtual` inheritance involved?

Comment: *"I cannot provide a minimum reproducible example that you can run"* Is this a confidentiality issue, or were you not successful? The problem you describe may very well be the result of UB, which could be caused by any of the code not shown.

Comment: @fabian No virtual inheritance, just a lot of multiple inheritance (perhaps a bit too much).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I agree.  But what I can't understand is, if I actually have a pointer that is correct to a class on which I am calling a non-virtual method, I would expect the offset to always be correct (the compiler knows it at compile time). But, looking at the assembly, it isn't.

Comment: I _must_ be possible to provide a small [mre] to show this. What stops you?

Comment: How did you get `0x2710`? What even is the issue?Why do you care about the assembly? `myClassPtr->_ptr` must do the right thing, does it not? Then you have C++ problem not assembly one and you must show C++ code not the generated assembly.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I've been trying, but so far I can't get anything to produce the same undefined result.  That's why I'm kind of hoping for some general "maybe you should check this"

Comment: It's normal for multiple inheritance to give inconsistent pointer addresses, because each parent type has a different memory layout. The compiler knows the offset from one type to another and applies it as appropriate.

Comment: Enabling ubsan and asan might be helpful

Comment: @Quimby I got it from using GDB which says the address of _ptr is 0x200083A8.  I then subtracted.  The reason I show the assembly is because a) this is an embedded system and b) The assembly seems incorrect.  The addition and offset does not result in the correct address of _ptr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else experiencing a problem like this, it cam down to a violation of the "One Definition Rule" caused by differing #define values in translation units.

For example, if the class definition was:

Foo.hpp:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    std::array<uint8_t, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE> _buffer;
    int _foo;
};
```

File A.cpp had MAX_BUFFER_SIZE defined as 10 when including Foo.hpp

File B.cpp had MAX_BUFFER_SIZE defined as 20 when including Foo.hpp

Thus the address of _foo differs between A.cpp from B.cpp, resulting in inconsistent assembly code.

In my actual application, the actual cause of the problem was a bit more involved (due to a typo in some include files), but it distilled down to this.